# Problem using Fill sink tool (SAGA) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, saga, fill, sink

I am trying to use the "fill sink" tool in QGIS, but it doesn´t work and I get the following log. What am I doing wrong?

```
QGIS version: 3.20.1-Odense
QGIS code revision: 1c3c5cd6
Qt version: 5.15.2
Python version: 3.9.5
GDAL version: 3.3.1
GEOS version: 3.9.1-CAPI-1.14.2
PROJ version: Rel. 8.1.0, July 1st, 2021
PDAL version: 2.3.0 (git-version: eac774)
SAGA Next Gen version: 0.0.7
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Fill sinks xxl (wang & liu)' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'ELEV' : 'Merged_DEM.tif', 'FILLED' : 'C:/Users/Ägaren/Desktop/Studier/Master thesis/Mines/GIS data/Pahtohavare/Fill_Sinks.sdat', 'MINSLOPE' : 0.1 }

io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM 1 -RESAMPLING 3 -GRIDS "C:/Users/Ägaren/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_GPJMYO/ece0d72b45184e8c8f6998e5d21345ef/MergedDEM.sgrd" -FILES "Merged_DEM.tif"
ta_preprocessor "Fill Sinks XXL (Wang & Liu)" -ELEV "C:/Users/Ägaren/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_GPJMYO/ece0d72b45184e8c8f6998e5d21345ef/MergedDEM.sgrd" -MINSLOPE 0.1 -FILLED "C:/Users/Ägaren/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_GPJMYO/3f3604133714464e887f6eaba2063d7a/FILLED.sdat"

Execution completed in 0.17 seconds
Results:
{'FILLED': 'C:/Users/Ägaren/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_GPJMYO/3f3604133714464e887f6eaba2063d7a/FILLED.sdat'}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• C:/Users/Ägaren/Desktop/Studier/Master thesis/Mines/GIS data/Pahtohavare/Fill_Sinks.sdat
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

In my "Log Message Panel", processing tab, it says:

```
2021-12-18T00:55:40     INFO    SAGA execution commands
             io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM 1 -RESAMPLING 3 -GRIDS "C:/Users/Ägaren/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_YqwZub/4773b1ebc3784a89ad1666771a589a91/OpenStreetMap.sgrd" -FILES "crs=EPSG:3857&format&type=xyz&url=https://tile.openstreetmap.org/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png&zmax=19&zmin=0"
             ta_preprocessor "Fill Sinks XXL (Wang & Liu)" -ELEV "C:/Users/Ägaren/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_YqwZub/4773b1ebc3784a89ad1666771a589a91/OpenStreetMap.sgrd" -MINSLOPE 0.1 -FILLED "C:/Users/Ägaren/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_YqwZub/eee040665c7e4f609c0ee8c71f781cbc/FILLED.sdat"
2021-12-18T00:55:40     INFO    SAGA execution console output
```

Comment: See the last line: "You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm." What does this say?

Comment: Sorry, I´m a total newbee to QGIS. The processing tab shows the following:

Comment: Can you put your file in somewhere without umlauts and spaces, and try again?